# How to fix black screen with GLFW

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm using GLEW and GLFW. My program builds successfully but when it runs, all I get is a black screen. I know it's not a problem with the shader code because I have tested the installShaders function in QT and it worked perfectly so I am assuming I am using GLFW incorrectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

GLFWwindow* window;

extern const char* vertexShaderCode;
extern const char* fragmentShaderCode;

void sendDataToOpenGL()
{
    GLfloat verts[] = 
{
    +0.0f, +1.0f,
    +1.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f, 
    -1.0f, -1.0f,
    +1.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f,
    +1.0f, -1.0f,
    +1.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f,
};
GLuint vertexBufferID;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 5, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 5, (char*)(sizeof(float) * 2));

GLushort indices[] = { 0,1,2 };
GLuint indexBufferID;
glGenBuffers(1, &indexBufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

void installShaders()
{
GLuint vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
GLuint fragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

const char* adapter[1]; 
adapter[0] = vertexShaderCode;
glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, 1, adapter, 0);
adapter[0] = fragmentShaderCode;
glShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, 1, adapter, 0);

glCompileShader(vertexShaderID);
glCompileShader(fragmentShaderID);

GLuint programID = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
glLinkProgram(programID);

glUseProgram(programID);
}

int main( void )
{
if( !glfwInit() )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
    return -1;
}

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "OpenGL Graphics", NULL, NULL);
if( window == NULL ){
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window.\n" );
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

glewExperimental = true; 
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
    return -1;
}

glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

sendDataToOpenGL();
installShaders();

do{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();

} 
while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
       glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

glfwTerminate();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to construct a more descriptive title

Comment: Please, don't write again "PLEASE HELP" in the title.

Comment: Where are your shaders?  Why isn't `installShaders()` checking the shader compilation/link statuses/logs?

Comment: Since I have just recently started learning OpenGL, I haven't learned much about shader compilation. I do know, however, that this is not an error with the shader code. I have tested the shader code in QT4 and it works fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're specifying an OpenGL 3.3 Core Profile in your startup code (`glfwWindowHint` calls). Your code is not compatible with the core profile. The use of vertex buffers and drawing without a Vertex Array Object (VAO) is deprecated. Under section "E.2.2 Removed Features" of the 3.3 spec:

> The default vertex array object (the name zero) is also deprecated. Calling VertexAttribPointer when no buffer object or no vertex array object is bound will generate an INVALID_OPERATION error, as will calling any array drawing command when no vertex array object is bound.

The first thing I would always do when you get no output is add a `glGetError()` call at the end of the drawing. In this case, you should see an error return, and can then add additional `glGetError()` calls to localize which OpenGL call triggered the error.

To verify if this is the only problem in your code, you could temporarily remove the `GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE` flag.

Comment: Sadly, the manual pages for vertex functions actually do not mention this behavior. Like `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY`, `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` has a lot of causes that are not documented in individual manual pages. You have to dig around in the full specification to figure this one out.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Yes. Took me some time with the specs to figure this one out the first time I ran into it. It's not only missing in the man page, but also fairly well hidden in the spec. Interestingly, ES 3.0/3.1 still allow this, but list it as a "legacy feature", saying "use is not recommended as it is likely for these features to be removed in a future version".